# Cannot access controller using angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im using Angular ui router for routing in my app but i came up with a particular issue as im not able to access ProfileCtrl. Im not getting any error at all in my console which makes this more weird. I can access all the rest of my controllers except ProfileCtrl. I dont know how to debug this issue but it seems like my route is not able to "read" whatever is in ProfileCtrl as if i delete everything it still not showing errors. This is my code so far.

```
angular.module('Chat', ['ngResource', 'ngMessages', 'ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'satellizer', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'angularFileUpload'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {     
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            })
            .state('profile', {
                url: '/profile',
                templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
                controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    authenticated: function($q, $location, $auth) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();

                        if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                            $location.path('/login');
                        } else {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        }

                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
 }]);
```

// Controller

```
angular.module('Chat')
.controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    console.log("test");


}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.state` is using the `resolve` option.  According to the angular-ui [Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve):

> resolve  is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.
>
> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the $stateChangeSuccess event is fired.

However, your controller is not accepting the value `authenticated` as a dependency.  Try changing your signature

`.controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope', 'authenticated' function($scope, authenticated) {`

and also verify that your dependency is actually returning a value; right now, it doesn't look like it's returning anything.

Comment: Hey Claies thanks for answering. I have tried injecting the dependency and i also checked is returning a value but im still unable to log. Even more i removed the resolve option and nothing. Im still wondering why is not accesing the controller and i cant find the way to debug.